# Is it safe to condense water into a liquid nitrogen trap?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, experimental-chemistry, purification

I'm trying to remove water from an imidazolium salt (i.e. dry the salt).  However I want to know if it is safe to remove the water under vacuum.  Is it safe to condense water into a liquid nitrogen trap?  Wouldn't the water freeze in the trap since the freezing temperature of water is 0 degrees Celcius?  Just curious b/c I was informed that it was ok to do it this way.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how much water!

Comment: Im not really sure the exact amount.  However, based off of the peak that I observed in the NMR spectra, it shouldnt be more than 15 mL of water.

Comment: The water does freeze in the trap so it'll work as long as it's not more than the trap's capacity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One use of a liquid nitrogen cold trap is to collect organic and water vapors that are removed from a system under vacuum.  In this case, the vapors are collected as ices (solids).  See [this reference](http://operatingexperience.doe-hss.wikispaces.net/file/view/Schlenk+Line+Safety.pdf) which has some useful information on Schlenk line safety and use.

Where you want to be cautious is when your collection is finished.  You do not want to keep a liquid nitrogen cold trap exposed to the atmosphere because oxygen will condense and cause an explosion hazard.  Typical procedures would include shutting of the vacuum pump, dismantling of the vacuum apparatus and allowing the trap to warm to room temperature (in a fume hood if organic vapors were collected).

Some additional references might be helpful, including [this one](http://kubiak.ucsd.edu/manual/schlenktech.php) that not only describes proper Schlenk line technique but also provides some good references; and you can see how liquid nitrogen traps are used for several industrial purposes [here](http://vacaero.com/information-resources/the-heat-treat-doctor/1225-cold-traps.html) and [here](http://www.sesco-inc.com/product_listing.aspx?Category=badcdc16-c31f-4484-9fa7-0af5d8ea82c1).

Comment: Thanks for the response bob.  I will check out the references you gave.